# SDL2 with OpenGL: how to achieve smooth and fast motion in a 2d game?

Tags: opengl, sdl, sdl-2, game-development

I'm creating a breakout like game, and I'm wanting to move the paddle...the orthographic projection matrix is equal to the screen size in pixels, so, if I set the paddles horizontal motion to adjust in one pixel increments, the motion is smooth, but it is not fast. If I increase the increment to 15 pixels, then the motion is fast, but it is not smooth. Is there a way to achieve this? Like with threads or something? My game's running at 60fps, and below is my main game loop:

```cpp
while (!quit) {
    wile (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        switch (event.type) {
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                key_handler(event.key.keysym.sym, event.type);
                break;
            case SDL_KEYUP:
                break;
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                active_scene->mouse_motion(event.motion.xrel, event.motion.yrel);
                break;
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: // 0, 0 is top left
                active_scene->mouse_click(event.button.button,event.button.x,event.button.y);
                break;
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit=true;
                break;
        }
    }
    active_scene->render();
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(Window);
}
```

Comment: If a 15px/frame movement at 60Hz is not smooth enough to you, you will need a higher frame rate.

Comment: There's no magic solution. If there's no lag, and your FPS is equal to the display refresh rate, and if you move by the same amount of pixels per frame, then you already have the smoothest possible motion. Then you need some artistic effects, such as accelerating the pad gradually, or having slight motion blur.

Comment: it's just that in android studio, where events are processed on a thread, and the display was 60fps, it always seemed smooth and fast. anyways, thanks for replying, guess there's nothin i can do abot it.

Comment: for the record, i figured out how to fix it. if you check the key state in the opengl render loop, then the motion is smooth even at 15px.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize that you used to perform the movement in `key_handler`. `SDL_KEYDOWN` doesn't fire every frame, instead it fires with a frequency determined by OS settings, the same frequency at which letters are typed if you hold down a key.